# RDS: RemoteApp notifications icon is not visible

Tags: notifications, icons, rds, remoteapp

I'm using Windows Server 2016 for Remote Desktop Services (RDS) the applications I've published are working fine. I've created a logon script so that my windows application starts when a user establishes RDS session. My problem is when a user logs in and my application runs automatically it doesn't show icon notification in system tray. I've gone through the below link and added the registry key which fixed the issue but it had also shown all unwanted application's icon as well.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/4122521f-7896-4098-a723-858077a243f1/remoteapp-notification-area-icons-not-visable?forum=winserverTS

Is there any way that I could programmatically dictate "rdpshell" to show only my application icon? or if there is any registry key specifically I could use for my application? or anything that I could use to show my application icon only?

Thanks.